# ServiceClient Caching Resutls

Tags: dataverse

I am using ServiceClient to access data in dataverse from a c# application.  The application is a worker service and the service client is injected into the application using dependency injection as a singleton.  I am seeing the service client cache results.   Is there a work around for this.  If I update the record in dataverse my application continues to pull the old data.

Answer (score 0):

It appears since my context was a singleton I needed to detatch any records that I may have already queried.

Comment: It may help others if you include some code snippets.  There are many ways to use the ServiceClient to interact with Dataverse records and not all of them follow this same behavior.